# Unexpected result with preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$subject = "'foo' = 'bar'";
$pattern = "/('foo' = ').*(')/";
$var = "123baz";
$replacement = "$1$var$2";
print_r(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject));
```

Result is `23baz'` instead of `'foo' = '123baz'`. Why and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you're looking for something like this:

```
$subject = "'foo' = 'bar'";
$pattern = "/(= ').*(')/";
$var = "123baz";
$replacement = "= '$var'";
print_r(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject));
```

Output:

```
'foo' = '123baz'
```

Comment: @a1277399 You're using a wrong pattern and so your replacement is wrong! your searching for: `'foo' = '*'`So you replace everything which matches this pattern with the replacement

Comment: @a1277399 yeah you could use it, but `$1` means the first `()` group get's replaced there, but since the variable at the start have a number it tries to replace it whith the `()` 1123 group which doesn't exists

Comment: That is, what I was assuming. How can I avoid this?

Comment: @a1277399 Out of my head i don't think that's possible, so for now my answer should work.

Comment: @a1277399 Your welcome! Have a nice day :D (I'll take a look if i find something, because it's very interesting!)

Comment: Thank you! Have a nice day, too! ;-) (That would be great! Actually a solution for that is exactly what I'm looking for.)

Comment: @a1277399 Since it's very iteresting you could make a new question if you want and describe your problem well and show the people where you stuck, what the problem is! I think with this way you get more people to look at and you get your answer faster! (Also make sure you tag it with `regex`)

Comment: Well, I don't really know how to better describe the problem. :-/

Comment: @a1277399 Have to solution! (It's every time the simplest Xd) just use `$replacement = '${1}' . $var . '${2}';` (With `{}` your like exactly say which number it is)

Comment: Does this work with PHP 5.2.17? Because with `$replacement = "${1}" . $var . "${2}";` I get `baz`.

Comment: Ups. You actually have to use single quotes. Do you know why? Thank you very much for your kind help. :)

Comment: @a1277399 Yes because there is a difference between single and double quotes!(http://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/3933332) If you put it in double quotes first the $ get's 'calculated' and php thinks it's a variable not a regex expression, so if you put it in single quotes that doesn't happen

Comment: I was aware of the difference, but not in that context. Thank you!